# "Missing $ inserted" although I have $

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have problem with this

```
$ \text{bredden = x \Leftrightarrow längden = 3 \cdot bredden = 3x} $
```

I get a

```
Missing $ inserted
```

error, although I have `$`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 26):

When using `\text{}` you escape `math mode`. Your line asks LaTeX to compile several `math` symbols (such as `\Leftrightarrow` and `\cdot`) inside a text environment, which explains the error message.

The proper way of writing your line would, in any `math` environment, be

```
\text{bredden} = x \Leftrightarrow \text{längden} = 3 \cdot \text{bredden} = 3x
```

(with `$ ... $` for your `inline math` case).

Answer (score 13):

The "computer science answer" is that when parsers encounter an error, a possible *error recovery* strategy in some situations is to guess that a token is missing in the input stream, and simply put it in and try parsing again.

The error recovery strategy is just a guess, and, as such, it might be wrong. So wording the diagnostic as "missing $ inserted" is misleading. Inserting `$` is just what the software did based on the *hypothesis* that a `$` is missing at that point.

So you have to take the diagnostic with a grain of salt. It really means *"Syntax error! trying to continue parsing by adding a dollar sign."*

In the olden days of computing, it was important for parsers to have clever error recovery schemes. The reason was that the turnaround time to have a program processed through a job submission window was very high, and so programmers benefited from having as many errors in the code diagnosed as possible in a single pass. It would not have been acceptable to stop after a single error, and not diagnose the program further, because then N round trips through the job submission queue would have been required to fix N compilation errors.

The steadfast efforts of a compiler to keep going in the face of errors may result in it becoming confused, and generating reams and reams of inappropriate diagnostics. *Creative Computing* magazine used to have a contest for users to submit programs which generate the longest reams of diagnostics from some compiler that they use.

Comment: This is a correct insight into the history of this kind of error, though in this case, there really is a `$` missing in the sense that `\Leftrightarrow` is a math mode-specific command.